# Adding a switch to an existing light

Tags: switches, bluetooth, light

I've read about 3-way and 4-way switches but I don't understand something.
I am aiming to create a bluetooth controlled home network. One of the modules would include a light switch. How would I go about adding it if an existing switch exists? **Without redoing all the wiring.** putting a relay on the wire would be easy, but then the manual switch would have to be on all the time :(.

Comment: Use X10 and a Bluetooth-to-X10 gateway.

Comment: Do you have a diagram (hand drawn on paper is okay) of the existing light switch and wiring? Is the existing light switch '3-way' (I'd call that single pole, double throw)? Are there three wires in the 'wall box' that the existing light switch is mounted in, or only two?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is a school project, I can't use that. Thx for that though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you currently have a 2-way switch or two 3-way switches in the room, so I'm going to include circuits for both.  That way if you (or someone else reading this answer in the future) encounter the other setup, you will be all set to go.

If you currently only have one switch controlling the light, it is called a 2-way switch and just has a simple on-off contact, switching the HOT lad to the lamp. So it will have just two wires connecting to it.

If you have two switches controlling the light, for example one at each of two doors, these are called 3-way switches and will have three wires connected to each one, the two switched wires connecting one switch with the other..  In either case, you will not have to change the wiring in the walls.

However if you have only the one 2-way switch, you will have to replace it with a 3-way switch.  Then you will be adding a SPDT relay, acting as a second 3-way switch.  You will want to place the relay as close to the existing switch as possible to minimize the extra wiring needed.

Here is the wiring:

[image]

I have not shown the wiring for the relay coil, that would be connected up to your Bluetooth device.

If you have two 3-way switches already, then you can leave them in place, and just add a DPDT relay, acting as a 4-way switch something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man. And thanks for providing both of the diagrams. I needed them both.

Comment: Ps, what program did you use for the diagrams? Eagle?

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić Yes, Eagle 6. I haven't upgraded to 7 yet. I do a screen capture and make a jpg that I can upload to the site.  Simple diagrams like this you can easily do with the free version.  I could have used the built-in CircuitLab editor, but I'm more proficient with Eagle at this point.